# MacroBenchmark giving error testInstrumentationRunnerArguments "EMULATOR,DEBUGGABLE"

Tags: android, macrobenchmark

I am getting below error while running macrobenchmark test for to measure  **App Startup Time**

```
testInstrumentationRunnerArguments["androidx.benchmark.suppressErrors"] = "EMULATOR,DEBUGGABLE"
}
```

the error says

```
ERROR: Running on Emulator
Benchmark is running on an emulator, which is not representative of
real user devices. Use a physical device to benchmark. Emulator
benchmark improvements might not carry over to a real user's
experience (or even regress real device performance).
```

SO my question is that is there any way execute banchmarks on android emulator